# AEM - data-sly-resource children html

Tags: aem

I want to figure out a way to insert HTML inside a `<sly data-sly-resource>` tag and be able to go inside the component I am retrieving from the resource attribute.

To compare, it would be something like Vue's `slots`, and React's `{ this.props.children }`.

Example:

**Parent Component**

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${'example' @ resourceType='path/to/component/structure/example'}">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</sly>
```

**Example Component**

```
<div id="example-component">
    ${ variable.getChildrenHTMLCall() } // Does something like this exist?
</div>
```

**Output**

```
<div id="example-component">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This functionality does not exist. You could make a *similar* functionality work with data-sly-template but you have to pass the html string as a parameter and not as a child element which might not be desired or maintainable.

Comment: maybe add your comment as an answer, @AhmedMusallam?

Answer (score 1):

**This functionality does not exist.**

You *could* make a *similar functionality* by using `data-sly-template`. But you’d have to pass the HTML sting as a parameter (more specifically `option`) but that might not be desired or maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `com.day.cq.contentsync.handler.util.RequestResponseFactory` as seen here: http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/10/get-rendered-html-for-an-aem-resource-or-component